# Can't control Downshift selectedItem prop from parent component using controlled props

Tags: reactjs, downshift

I wrote a reusable autocomplete component using Downshift. The component encapsulates a lot of Relay logic for fetching data from my GraphQL endpoint. I have a use case where the parent component needs to receive the selectedItem, display the name property of the selectedItem, then clear out the selectedItem of the autocomplete (think selecting and displaying multiple tags).

Problem is I can't seem to control the selectedItem of the autocomplete from the parent component. I'm sending down the selectedItem as null to the autocomplete yet the inputValue/selectedItem remains the chosen item.

Sample code with Relay stripped out for simplicity:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/spring-fire-um1xh

**Steps to reproduce**

- Type the word "Item" into the textbox
- Click on one of the three results that are displayed

**Actual outcome**

- Title of parent component and inputValue/selectedItem of autocomplete are both set to value of item chosen

**Desired Outcome**

- Title of parent component set to value of item chosen
- inputValue/selectedItem of autocomplete cleared out

Comment: change setSelectedItem(null) into setSelectedItem("") will clear the input

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. This code needs alot of refactor but it works anyway as desired. So, i just added inputValue props on Downshift as per doc.

```
----- index.js -------
function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("Select an Item");
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(""); //added these two to control input of inputbox

  const onItemSelected = selectedItem => {
    setTitle(selectedItem.name);
    setSelectedItem(null);
    setInputValue("") // after selection clear input
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <Autocomplete
        selectedItem={selectedItem}
        inputValue={inputValue} // passed down inputValue and setInputValue
        setInputValue={setInputValue}
        onItemSelected={onItemSelected}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

----Autocomplete.js--------
function Autocomplete({ selectedItem, onItemSelected, inputValue, setInputValue })  { // get those props
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const onInputValueChanged = e => {
    setInputValue(e.currentTarget.value) //change a input on inputchange
    const items = data.filter(f => f.name.includes(e.currentTarget.value));
    setItems(items);
  };

  return (
    <Downshift
      inputValue={inputValue} //added
      selectedItem={selectedItem}
      onChange={onItemSelected}
      itemToString={i => (i ? i.name : "")}
    >
      {({ getInputProps, getItemProps, getMenuProps, isOpen }) => (
        <div>
          <input {...getInputProps({ onChange: onInputValueChanged })} />
          <ul {...getMenuProps()}>
            {isOpen &&
              items.map(item => (
                <li {...getItemProps({ item, key: item.value })}>
                  {item.name}
                </li>
              ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </Downshift>
  );
}
```